# Using variables within Attributes in C#

Tags: c#, variables, attributes

We have some Well-Attributed DB code, like so:

```
[Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Since it is quite generic we'd like to use it again, but with a different string in the Name part of the attribute.  Since it's an attribute it seems to want things to be const, so we tried:

```
const string AddressType = "Student ";
[Display(Name = AddressType + "Phone Number")]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

This seems to work alright, except that having a const string means we can't overwrite it in any base classes, thereby removing the functionality that we originally were intending to add, and exposing my question:

Is there a way to use some sort of variable inside of an attribute so that we can inherit and keep the attribute decorations?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Everything inside an attribute must be known to the compiler at compile-time.  Variables are inherently variable (!) so can't be used in attributes.

If you can use a code generation tool, you'd be able to dynamically inject different (constant) values into each derived class.

Comment: That's too bad, but I figured as such.  Thanks.

Comment: That's too bad indeed. However, there should be such use cases, are there nice alternatives?

Comment: Does this also justify why we cannot use a `static readonly String` as attribute argument? Edit: Nevermind, we can use a `const String`.

Comment: Can we use stuff defined in ```appsettings.json```?

Answer (score 4):

You could jump through hoops and use an additional attribute to define the variable portion, but that would be quite a bit of work compared to what it would produce. There's no simple way to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: I briefly considered my own attribute, but I think the extra work would not justify the saved work.  It's a simple problem on my end of things, but not when it has to be compiled.