# How can I use a variable in [Authorize(Roles="")]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 C# intranet web application where we have over 30 Active Directory roles in use, and permissions are often a changing thing due to the business culture.

To make things easy for myself, I thought I would try something like this to determine who is allowed access to a controller action or child action.

```
/* This function runs a LINQ query and outputs a comma delimited string of 
   approved active directory roles.
*/

    private static string _approvedRoles = 
            Helpers.QueryableExtensions.GetApprovedRoles("FourCourseAudit");

    // GET: FourCourseAudits    
    [Authorize(Roles = _approvedRoles)]
    public ActionResult Index(string searchBy="All", 
          string orderBy="Campus", string orderDir="Asc")
    {

    // and so on...
```

Unfortunately, I get this compile time error: `An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`.

This is where I am after trying other approaches with the `_approvedRoles` variable, such as `public const string` and `public string`. I placed the `GetApprovedRoles` function in the model, in the repository (where it is now), and in the body of the controller.

I know the roles are good because if I use this: `[Authorize(Roles="DOMAIN\Role1,DOMAIN\Role2")]` it works. And that's not a feasible option for me because the roles change and this is a very large MVC site. Is there some way I can let Roles be a variable?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827799/using-variables-within-attributes-in-c-sharp

Comment: Attributes (as the error says) are not dynamic in that they can't have values that change runtime. I don't use MVC in ASP but the other frameworks I use allow me to examine the context of the request to get the user's roles and compare them inside the method and return an error if they are not allowed...

Comment: so you want to override the attribute

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The arguments need to be known at compile time, but your query happens at run time.

The easiest way to do this is to create a [custom AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357(v=vs.91).aspx). Inside the `Authorize()` method, you can do any checks you want, including querying a database. You can also pass custom parameters into the constructor, if you want more flexibility in reusing the attribute. As an example:

```
public class RoleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // or inject it
    private DbContext _db = new DbContext();

    private string _filter;

    public RoleAuthorizeAttribute(string filter)
    {
        _filter = filter;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check authorization
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User;

        // do some checks, query a database, whatever
        string approvedRoles =  Helpers.QueryableExtensions.GetApprovedRoles(_filter);

        if (!currentUser.IsInRole(...))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Error", new RouteValueDictionary());
        }
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
[RoleAuthorize("FourCourseAudit")]
```

Comment: I also sometimes directly inherit from `Attribute` which is what `AuthorizeAttribute` inherits from

Comment: This looks promising. How would I apply this override in relation to a specific string, such as "FourCourseAudit"? In my example, I returned approved roles using that string as the where filter.

Comment: I updated with an example of how to pass a parameter to the attribute, like the "FourCourseAudit". In terms of how you actually check that, it depends on what your GetApprovedRoles() returns, and what your business logic should be.

Comment: Almost there. No compile time errors, but when I tried it, I got an HTTP 500 error. Do I have to save this class in a particular namespace or folder?

Comment: Nope, it can go anywhere. What is the error? You might need to enable breaking on thrown exceptions (In the Debug menu > Exceptions > and make sure Common Language Runtime Exceptions is checked for Thrown).

Comment: I got it to work. In my case I had to use `filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult (new RouteValueDictionary (new { controller = "Home", action = "Forbidden" }));`

Comment: Ah yeah, that line assumed a route named `Error`. The stuff inside `OnAuthorization()` is just for example. Feel free to change any of it to support your specific use.

Comment: This solved it for me as we want to configure access roles in Web.config

Answer (score 11):

This is a simple version for any who want it:

```
public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRolesAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        Roles = String.Join(",", roles);
    }
}
```

Usage is then:

```
[AuthorizeRoles(RoleConstant1,RoleConstant2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order the compilation of your code to be successfull, you should do what is stated in the error message you have posted.

For instance, you could try something like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User")]
```

In simple terms the values you pass to the an attribute as parameters should be known at the time of compilation. They cannot be evaluated at the runtime.

**Update**

As I stated in my comment below:

The only alternative is to build a custom attribute and get there the approved roles. Then you could check if the current's user role is in the approved roles and your custom attribute - your filter - would allow or not to the use to call this action.

Comment: Thank you. I am already aware of that. I was hoping that there was another approach that would allow for use of a variable.

Comment: The only alternative is to build a custom attribute and get there the approved roles. Then you could check if the current's user role is in the approved roles and your custom attribute - your filter -  would allow or not to the use to call this action.

Answer (score 0):

you can always define new class that extend from **AuthorizeAttribute** and ovveride **AuthorizeCore** and  **HandleUnauthorizedRequest**
and create a static class with all constant role declare that how i do in my application.

example of code in my custom class attribute inside **AuthorizeCore** method

```
    public string Groups { get; set; } // this will be my new attribute
    var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList();

    var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"myDomain");
    var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,IdentityType.SamAccountName,httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

    foreach(var group in groups){ // will iterate the attribute and check if that user log is in that group
     if(userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group)){
                            return true;
     }
   }
```